# Digitizing against PDF in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, georeferencing, pdf

I am relatively new to GIS and am using ArcGIS Pro. I am making a map of a property that includes a watercourse and an environmental setback from the watercourse. I need to add the development plans to the map, which were given to me as a PDF (not georeferenced). The CAD file is not available.

Is it possible to add the PDF to the map so I can trace or draw the polygons?

I suppose it would have to be transparent so I could line it up with the property boundaries.

Or perhaps I could geo-reference it?

Comment: If you have Adobe Illustrator you can open the pdf and save as dxf or dwg then you can geo-reference in arcgis pro. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/cad/georeferencing-cad-data.htm

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I tried converting the PDF to DWG in a free online conversion tool and it looked like it worked, but I kept getting an error when I tried to add it to the map. But it it worked when I converted it using Illustrator.

Comment: Opensource Inkscape worked for me also: import a pdf saved from CAD, save as dxf, open in pro. You can even georeference that dxf in pro.